# Change excel cell text based on content

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to make a VBA in excel that changes the content of a cell based on the text in the cells. All the cells I want to change contains a structure of "< (space) 0.005" the number however varies a lot and setting up all the different numbers would take too long. 
I have a base for an older project but I can't seem to tweak it to the required needs.

```
Sub FillEmptyBlankCellWithValue()
Dim cell As Range
Dim InputValue As String
On Error Resume Next
InputValue = InputBox("Enter value that will fill empty cells in selection", _
"Fill Empty Cells")
For Each cell In Selection
If IsEmpty(cell) Then
cell.Value = InputValue
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So you want `< 0.005` in all the blank cells in the selection..?

Comment: Is the pattern always <\s\d\.\d{3}   ? I am assuming (space) means < 0.005

Comment: QHarr, yes the pattern is always like that.

Comment: But it is not always d{3}, that ranges from 1-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on a right track. But in general I'd avoid using `Selection` or any other `Select` operations as they are prone to many errors.

Instead, I'd recommend using active (detected dynamic) range, or let the user define the range. eg.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub fill_blanks

Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' set yours
Dim firstcell as String, lastcell as String, fillvalue as String
Dim datarange as Range

firstcell  = InputBox("Enter the starting cell of your data range")
lastcell = InputBox("Enter the last cell of your data range")
fillvalue = InputBox("Enter the value to fill blank cells with")

Set datarange = ws.Range(Trim(firstcell) & ":" & Trim(lastcell))

Dim cell as Range
For each cell in datarange
   If IsEmpty(cell) Then
        cell = fillvalue
   End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

> You could also let them define the range inside a pre-defined cells in
>   the worksheet, or detect the active range with `.End(xlUp)` for row
>   and `.End(xlToLeft)` for column. Up to you really..

---

*Note: This will paste the result as a `String` (or "Text") as a Cell Format, you also need to change the `Range.Format` property.*